# Styles not updating inside Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react-native component with PanResponder. I want to drag the entire container and specify the required styles. But I can see for a fact that the styles are not getting updated; the view is not getting refreshed.

Even if I use the `componentDidMount()` method and do change of background color with a setTimeout the styles don't seem to re-render the view.

On another class I am doing the same thing with PanResponder and dragging to increase height. And it's working there. What seems to be the trouble?

Here is the code.

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react-native');
var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
var Story = require('./Story');

var {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  PanResponder
} = React;

// <Story data={data[0]} />
// {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}

var width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
var height = Dimensions.get('window').height;
var styles = {
    wrapper: { flex: 1 },
    container: { flex: 1, left: 0, width: width, height: height },
};

var StoryContainer = React.createClass({
    componentWillMount: function(){
        this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
            onStartShouldSetPanResponder: this.handleStartShouldSetPanResponder,
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: this.handleMoveShouldSetPanResponder,
            onPanResponderGrant: this.handlePanResponderGrant,
            onPanResponderMove: this.handlePanResponderMove,
            onPanResponderRelease: this.handlePanResponderEnd,
            onPanResponderTerminate: this.handlePanResponderEnd,
        });
    },

    componentDidMount: function(){
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('updating styles');
            styles.container.backgroundColor = '#000000';
            that.forceUpdate();
        }, 4000);
    },

    render: function(){
        var data = this.props.data;
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Story data={data[0]} />
            </View>
        )
    },

    handleStartShouldSetPanResponder: function(evt: Object, gestureState: Object){
        return true;
    },

    handleMoveShouldSetPanResponder: function(evt: Object, gestureState: Object){
        return true;
    },

    handlePanResponderGrant: function(evt: Object, gestureState: Object){
        // return true;
    },

    handlePanResponderMove: function(evt: Object, gestureState: Object){
        console.log(gestureState.dx);
        styles.container.left = styles.container.left + gestureState.dx;
        this.forceUpdate();
    },

    handlePanResponderEnd: function(evt: Object, gestureState: Object){
        // end this sucker
    }
});

module.exports = StoryContainer;
```

Comment: Quick comment: the styles var is not initialized with StyleSheet.create ({ ... }). Could be the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using React wrong.

1. Get rid of all global variables, `setTimeout`, and `forceUpdate`
2. Understand the difference between props and state
3. Use `this.setState()` to update your state and `this.state.X` to make use of it in your `render()` function.